# Error: build error: Failed to push image: received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: node.js, openshift-origin

I am getting the following error when deploying nodejs application to openshift origin from my git repository...

Pushing image 172.30.210.239:5000/nodev6/node3v6:latest ...
Pushed 0/9 layers, 1% complete

Pushed 1/9 layers, 12% complete

Pushed 2/9 layers, 24% complete

Pushed 3/9 layers, 34% complete

Pushed 4/9 layers, 47% complete

Pushed 5/9 layers, 58% complete

Pushed 6/9 layers, 71% complete

Pushed 7/9 layers, 88% complete

Registry server Address:

Registry server User Name: serviceaccount

Registry server Email: serviceaccount@example.org

Registry server Password: <>

error: build error: Failed to push image: received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error

Don't know whats wrong with my docker container or openshift ...
what steps should i follow for the resolution... what installations needed or what commands needs to run...

Comment: Sometimes this can occur on the first push after a build as credentials haven't been synced between nodes quickly enough. If you do a re-build it should then work. Is this a transient thing or are you seeing this every time and is always failing?

Comment: Thanks Graham for your response.
Getting the same error every time i wanted to publish the app...

Comment: And this is an OpenShift cluster you set up yourself? If yes, you may be better to ask on one of the mailing lists at https://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshiftmm/listinfo